Finding the minimum value of a fraction that includes a floor
I am trying to come up with a way of finding the value of $x$ for which this function is minimized:
$$
f(x) = \frac{\left\lfloor \frac{xC}{B}+1 \right\rfloor}{x}
$$
where $x, C$, and $B$ are positive integers, $C$ and $B$ are constant, $C < B$ and, $x < M$.
I do not care if the solution is a formula or an algorithm. The only constraint is that $M$ is large enough that a brute-force linear search over $x$ will be way too slow (same goes for $C$ and $B$).
I have been banging my head against the wall for a while now, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

I don't know if this is of any help but have you tried finding the value that minimises $h(x) = \frac{\frac{xC}{B}+1}{x}$ which we will denote by $h_{\mathrm{min}}$. Then I'd expect $f_{\mathrm{min}}$ to be close to $h_{\mathrm{min}}$. By close I mean that if $m$ is the closest integer approximation of $h_{\mathrm{min}}$ then Id expect $f_{\mathrm{min}} \in {x-1,x,x+1}$. Ultimately these are my first guesses, they need checking first.

This has some interesting properties. The minimum clearly approaches $\frac{C}{B}$, with a new minimum reached at regular intervals as $x$ increases. The consequence is that the minimum with $x<M$ will occur with $x\ge M-B$.

For any real number $\xi$ we have $\lfloor \xi\rfloor > \xi -1$, so $
f(x) > \frac{C}{B}$. Suppose now that we take $y = n\frac{B}{C}-\varepsilon$ where $n$ is some positive integer and $\varepsilon$ is some sufficiently small positive real number. Then
$$
f(y) = \frac{\lfloor \left(n + 1\right)-  \varepsilon\frac{C}{B} \rfloor}{n \frac{B}{C}-\varepsilon} = \frac{n}{n \frac{B}{C} - \varepsilon} = \frac{C}{B}\left( 1+ \frac{\varepsilon}{n \frac{B}{C}- \varepsilon}\right) \tag{1}
$$
What we obtain is that if $\varepsilon$ is small enough then we can get arbitrarily close to the lower bound $\frac{C}{B}$.
This motivates us to search for values of $x$ such that $n\frac{B}{C}-x= \varepsilon$ for small $\varepsilon$, or in other words, that $n\frac{B}{C}$ is slightly greater than an integer $x$ in the range of $[1,M]$, and that integer would hopefully be the minimum value. We can translate being "slightly greater than an integer" to saying that the fractional part $\varepsilon$ is very small, so we'll look for an integer $n$ such that the fractional part $\{n\frac{B}{C}\}$ is the smallest (non $0$) out of all $1 \le n< \frac{MC}{B}$.
If we reduce the fraction such that $\frac{B}{C} = \frac{B'}{C'}$ and $B',C'$ are coprime, then for $k \in \mathbb{Z}^+$
$$
\left\{(k+C')\frac{B}{C}\right\} = \left\{k\frac{B'}{C'}+B'\right\} = \left\{k\frac{B'}{C'}\right\} = \left\{k\frac{B}{C}\right\}
$$
so the fractional part multiples have a period of $C'$. What good does this do? If $\varepsilon = \left\{k\frac{B}{C}\right\}$ then $\varepsilon = \left\{(k+jC')\frac{B}{C}\right\}$ for all positive integers $j$. So if we plug $\lfloor (k+jC')\frac{B}{C}\rfloor$, $\lfloor (k+(j+1)C')\frac{B}{C}\rfloor$ into $(1)$ we see that
$$
f\left(\left\lfloor (k+jC')\frac{B}{C}\right\rfloor\right)-f\left(\left\lfloor (k+(j+1)C')\frac{B}{C}\right\rfloor\right) =\varepsilon\left(\frac{1}{(k+jC')\frac{B}{C} - \varepsilon} - \frac{1}{(k+(j+1)C')\frac{B}{C} - \varepsilon} \right)  >0 \tag{2}
$$
where we get that $a_j = f\left(\left\lfloor (k+jC')\frac{B}{C}\right\rfloor\right)$ is a decreasing sequence.
Let's now say that $n$ is such that $\left\{n\frac{B}{C}\right\}$ is the smallest for all $n$ in $1 \le n \le C'$. By periodicity we would have that $\left\{(n+jC')\frac{B}{C}\right\}$ is the smallest for all $n$ in $1+jC' \le n \le (j+1)C'$. But since $f\left(\left\lfloor (k+jC')\frac{B}{C}\right\rfloor\right)$ is decreasing, if $f\left(\left\lfloor n\frac{B}{C}\right\rfloor\right)$ is minimum in $1 \le n \le C'$ then $f\left(\left\lfloor (n+jC')\frac{B}{C}\right\rfloor\right)$ would be the minimum for all positive integers up to $(n+jC')\frac{B}{C} <M$.
So to recap, if we find the integer $n$ from $1$ to $C'$ such that $\left\{n\frac{B}{C}\right\}$ is smallest and is such that $f\left(\left\lfloor n\frac{B}{C}\right\rfloor\right)$  is locally minimum, then by periodicity of $C'$ we can find the minimum overall. So how small can $\left\{n\frac{B}{C}\right\}$ be? By construction, the smallest would be if $\left\{n\frac{B}{C}\right\} = \frac{1}{C'}$, which would happen if
$$
nB' \equiv 1 \pmod{C'}
$$
And since $B',C'$ are coprime we know that there exists a unique solution modulo $C'$. This solution $n$ is called the modular multiplicative inverse of $B'$ modulo $C'$, because when multiplied they give $1$. Moreover $
nB' \equiv s \pmod{C'}
$ has a unique solution $1\le n\le C'$ for all $1 \le s \le C'$. This means that all $\left\{n\frac{B}{C}\right\}$ are of the form $\frac{s}{C'}$, where $0 \le s < C'$.
If we supposed now that $f\left(\left\lfloor m\frac{B}{C}\right\rfloor\right)$ was the minimum of $f$ for $1 \le m \le C'$ and $\left\{m\frac{B}{C}\right\} \neq\frac{1}{C'}$ then we would have $\left\{m\frac{B}{C}\right\} = \frac{s}{C'}$ with $s \ge 2$. If $n$ is such that $\left\{n\frac{B}{C}\right\} = \frac{1}{C'}$ for $1\le n\le C'$, plugging this into $(1)$ we would get that
$$
f\left(\left\lfloor m\frac{B}{C}\right\rfloor\right) <f\left(\left\lfloor n\frac{B}{C}\right\rfloor\right)  \implies \frac{\frac{s}{C'}}{m\frac{B}{C} - \frac{s}{C'}}< \frac{\frac{1}{C'}}{n\frac{B}{C} - \frac{1}{C'}}\implies m>sn \tag{3}
$$
We now analyze two sub-cases:

If $n > \frac{C'}{s}$ then by $(3)$ we would get $m > C'$, which is impossible as $m$ is the solution with $1 \le m \le C'$.
If $n \le \frac{C'}{s}$ then  $s n\le C'$. By definition of $n$ we know $nB' \equiv 1 \pmod{C'}$, and multiplying by $s$ we get $(sn)B' \equiv s \pmod{C'}$. So we've found a solution to $x B' \equiv s \pmod{C'}$ modulo $C'$, but since $m$ is the unique solution for $1 \le m \le C'$ then $ns = m$, which contradicts $(3)$.

This tells us that if $nB' \equiv 1\pmod{C'}$ then $f\left(\left\lfloor n\frac{B}{C}\right\rfloor\right)$ is indeed the minimum of $f$ for $1 \le n \le C'$, and by $(2)$ gives us the minimum overall.

Here's an example of the algorithm. Let's take $B=10$, $C=6$ and $M = 25$.

We reduce the fraction $\frac{C}{B} = \frac{6}{10} = \frac{3}{5}$, so $B' = 5$ and $C' = 3$ (you can skip this if $B$ and $C$ are already coprime).
We solve the congruence $n B' \equiv 1 \pmod{C'}$ for $n$ with $ 1 \le n \le C'$, which in our case is $5n \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$. This gives $\color{purple}{n = 2}$ as the solution for $1\le n \le 3$.
We find the biggest integer $j$ such than $n+jC' = \color{purple}{2} + 3j$ is less than $\frac{MC}{B}$. This corresponds to $j = \lfloor\frac{\frac{MC}{B}-n}{C'}\rfloor = \lfloor\frac{\frac{25\cdot 3}{5}-2}{3}\rfloor = \color{orange}{4} $.
We calculate $x =\lfloor (n+jC')\frac{B}{C}\rfloor =\lfloor (\color{purple}{2}+\color{orange}{4}\cdot 3)\frac{5}{3}\rfloor = 23$, and this is the minimum for all integers up to $M=25$.

One observation is that this method doesn't work if $M$ is smaller than $\lfloor n \frac{B}{C}\rfloor$, as we won't get to reach even our first "periodic minimum" yet. In that case you would be working with a small enough $M$ that computing the terms up to $M$ is the easiest to finding the minimum, but since you mentioned interest in large $M$ this shouldn't be a problem for your case.

Wow. Thanks a lot! This is awesome :)

So, I've implemented the algorithm above and it works great. Unfortunately, for some of the inputs I need it to run for, it ends up in the case where $M$ is smaller than $\left\lfloor n\frac{B}{C} \right\rfloor$. Is there a way the solution could be changed so that it can handle those cases as well? (Example inputs: $M=16777215$, $B=10^{19}$, and $C=(2^{44}) % (10^{19})$)
